# Sahadev's method of prediction

Tags: mahabharata, astrology, sahadeva

It is said that Sahadev used a specific chart for his prediction.
May I have a glimpse of same please if available. 
Also, please share any instruction on how it works

Comment: I remember no such thing

Comment: Not mentioned in authentic versions of mahabharat

Comment: I agree with Sahadev, no such chart is mentioned though it is said that he was a good astrologer.